# Inline substitution to create raster filenames using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro to set up an iterative work flow to analyse satellite images.

The input tiff files have long files names such as: 5023109_2010-06-21_RE1_3A_Analytic_clip.tif

I am trying to use inline substitution to give output rasters shorter filenames. For example:
"R"+"%Name%"[10:17], where Name is the variable representing the name of the input tiff.

I have read other discussions on this, but haven’t managed to solve the problem.

Comment: For example: in the model in Make Raster Layer, Parameter: Output raster layer name is "R"+"%Name%"[10:17]
This doesn’t create the expected raster layer name R10-06-21, so the next step falls over. Exporting the model to python, produces the following code for the MakeRasterLayer step:
# Process: Make Raster Layer arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(in_raster=Raster, out_rasterlayer=v_R____Name___10_17_, where_clause="", envelope="377500 6182870 380000 6184300", band_index="5")

Comment: If you have additional information to add to your question please do that using the [edit] button beneath it.

Comment: When you "read other discussions on this" were any of those "discussions" actually Q&As on this site?  If so, please included links to them within your question body.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is in how your are slicing the string and then concatenating that's causing it to fail. If you are constructing new names in this manner you should really do it in the Calculate Value tool as shown below. Trying to slice something within a parameter is unlikely to work or at best be confusing as to what it is you are really trying to achieve.

[image: Model]

The Calculate value tool is set up as shown:

[image: Calculate Value tool]

Notes:

1. Data type is set to any value, string did not seem to work
2. The output of the calculate value tool is a *precondition* to the Make raster Layer tool
3. The Raster dataset coming out of the iterator is the input into Make Raster Layer but is also a *precondition* to the Calculate Value tool. This ensures correct order of tool runs.
4. You use the output of calculate values as inline substitution for the raster layer name.